# Wordpress NavXT plugin localization

Tags: localization, wp-config, breadcrumb, translation

My situation is as follows:

1) I am using wordpress 3.6.1, and I have the [Breadcrumb NavXT plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/) installed.

2) I have a custom theme, and the localization file is on the following path: theme_folder/languages/ar_AR.mo file

I want the path in breadcrumbs to be localized (i.e. let "mywebsite > My Account" appear in local language instead of English).

1) I changed wp-config.php to be: define('WPLANG', 'ar_AR');

2) I added the labels that appear in the breadcrumbs (i.e. My Account) to the PO file, and generated a new MO file (using POEdit), and uploaded the new MO file to the path: theme_folder/languages/ar_AR.mo file

After doing the steps above, NOT all of the labels in the breadcrumbs path are translated in the webpage (some of them are successfully translated), although they are translated in PO file.

So the questions is: What should I do in order to translate the breadcrumbs path?

Comment: Please link to a plugin so that it is easier to look it up and check what it is doing in code.

Comment: The plugin link is http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/